# How to get JSON String value?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
var responseFromServer =
  // lines split for readability
  "{\"flag\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"result\":{\"ServicePermission\":true,"
  +  "\"UserGroupPermission\":true}}";
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var responseValue = serializer.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

responseFromServer value is get a webservice, and then how to get the JSON string value, such as "flag"，"Servicepermission"？？

affix: i'm sorry, using c#  to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: The JavaScriptSerializer is actually the slowest JSON Serializer I've ever benchmarked. So much so I've had to remove it from [my benchmarks](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) because it was taking too long (>100x slower).

Anyway this easily solved using [ServiceStack.Text's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/mythz/ServiceStack.Text):

```
var response = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string,string>>(responseFromServer);
var permissions = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string,string>>(response["result"]);
Console.WriteLine(response["flag"] + ":" + permissions["ServicePermission"]);
```

For completeness this would also work with ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer:

```
public class Response
{
    public bool flag { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Permisions result { get; set; }
}
public class Permisions
{
    public bool ServicePermission { get; set; }
    public bool UserGroupPermission { get; set; }
}

var response = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Response>(responseFromServer);
Console.WriteLine(response.flag + ":" + response.result.ServicePermission);
```

Comment: +1 for the answer but the link to the JSON Serializer is broken. This is the updated url: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

Answer (score -1):

```
    if u are using jQuery u can do this

    var json=jQuery.parseJSON(responseFromServer);

    //acess
    alert(json.ServicePermission);

if you are asing microsoft ajax do this

var json=Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(responseFromServer,true);

    //acess
    alert(json.ServicePermission);
```

in c# like php i have'nt seen any method that converts json to object on the fly. To do conversions in c# you must first create a class for this.

For your case you can do like this

//define classes

```
public class Response
{
    public bool flag { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Permisions result { get; set; }
}
public class Permisions
{
    public bool ServicePermission { get; set; }
    public bool UserGroupPermission { get; set; }
}


        var responseFromServer =
            // lines split for readability
  "{\"flag\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"result\":{\"ServicePermission\":true,"
  + "\"UserGroupPermission\":true}}";
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var responseValue = serializer.Deserialize<Response>(responseFromServer);

    //access     
    responseValue.result.ServicePermission
```

Comment: i'm sorry, using c# to do this.

Comment: yes, it's. i have a webservice such as Authentication.ashx，and i using c# in default.aspx.cs，i can get the result, and then want to parse the json string.